# How to read in and store x,y data from multiple text files (in one directory)

Tags: python, arrays, loops, text, graph

I have around 150 text files that I want to load data from and then plot to a scatter graph. Files are being loaded using `numpy.loadtxt` as follows:

```
x,y=loadtxt('2.8k to 293k 15102014_rerun 147_0K.txt',skiprows=1,unpack=True,dtype=float,delimiter=",")
```

How can I load the ~150 files from a given folder and plot them all.

Comment: Can you add more information regarding the format of the input files (columns) and what sort of graph you wish to draw? Have you attempted any code yet?

Comment: For example:

x,y=loadtxt('2.8k to 293k 15102014_rerun 147_0K.txt',skiprows=1,unpack=True,dtype=float,delimiter=",")

Is what usually loads in my text files. 

The graph is a simple line/scatter graph. I am not quite sure where to start on this. I was thinking of using os.getcwd first off?

Comment: Do you want all files plotted on the same plot?

Comment: Different graphs. Was going to incorporate a save picture function.

Comment: Ah, will update with an edit.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The following reads all files in the current folder named `*.txt` and then plots them to an interactive plot with `matplotlib`. I use the `glob` module for the directory listing for the wildcard matching, if you just want *all* files you can use `os.listdir('.')`.

```
import glob
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.clf()
plt.subplot(111)
for f in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    print(f)
    x, y=np.loadtxt(f,skiprows=1,unpack=True,dtype=float,delimiter=",")
    plt.scatter(x,y)

plt.show()
```

The following instead outputs each set of data` to a different plot - with the name taken from the name of the input file.

```
import glob
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for f in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    base_name = f[:-4]
    print(f)
    fig = plt.figure() 
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

    x, y=np.loadtxt(f,skiprows=1,unpack=True,dtype=float,delimiter=",")
    ax.scatter(x,y)

    fig.savefig(base_name+'.png')
```